# Use already existing Hosting URL from Heroku for a Facebook App

Tags: facebook, heroku

What do I have to do if I already have a hosting url from Heroku and want to use it for one of my already created app?

Apparently the 'Get One' button creates a new Heroku app for me. How to make it allow me to use one already created one?

Answer (score 2):

Just use existing URL in your application settings for **Canvas URL** / **Secure Canvas URL** / **Site URL**.

[image: Application settings]